# PDE : $2x(y + z) dx + (2yz - x^2 + y^2 - z^2) dy + (2yz - x^2 - y^2 + z^2) dz = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I want to solve the partial differential equation $$2x(y + z) dx + (2yz - x^2 + y^2 - z^2) dy + (2yz - x^2 - y^2 + z^2) dz = 0$$
Here is the step that I followed :
By putting $u=y+z, v=y-z$, then we have :
$$4xudx+(u^2-v^2-2x^2)du+2uvdv=0 $$
For $X=(4xu, u^2-v^2-2x^2,2uv)$ then $X rot(X)=0$, hence the condition of integrability is satisfied.
I take $x=cste$, so $dx=0$. Hence
$$(u^2-2x^2)du+(2uvdv-v^2du)=0 $$
$$ (u^2-2x^2)du-v^4d(\frac{u}{v^2})=0$$
From integration :
$$ \frac{1}{3}u^3-2x^2u-uv^2=C(x)$$
Differentiation to the above equation

$$u^2du-2x^2du-4xudx-v^2du-2uvdv-C'(x)dx=0 $$
Associate this with the initial equation
$4xudx+(u^2-v^2-2x^2)du+2uvdv=0 $ :
$$\frac{4xu}{-4xu-C'(x)}=\frac{u^2-v^2-2x^2}{u^2-2x^2-v^2}=\frac{2uv}{-2uv}$$
$$\frac{4xu}{-4xu-C'(x)}=1=-1 $$
This is not contradictory ?

Comment: The condition of integrability is *not* satisfied. For instance, $\frac{\partial}{\partial u}(4xu)=4x\neq \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(u^2-v^2-2x^2)=-4x$.

Comment: Integrability condition here is in the Sens of " complete integrability ", ie if $Pdx+Qdy+Rdz=0$, the complete integrability is the condition $(P,Q,R).rot((P,Q,R))=0$. We can refer this link "https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Pfaffian_equation"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$4xudx+(u^2-v^2-2x^2)du+2uvdv=0 \quad\text{is OK.} \tag 1$$
The mistake is in the integration.$\quad \int v^4d(\frac{u}{v^2})$ because $v^4$ isn't constant.

Calculus from  Eq.(1)$/u^2$ :
$$4\frac{x}{u}dx+\left(1-\frac{v^2}{u^2}-2\frac{x^2}{u^2}\right)du+2\frac{v}{u}dv=0 $$
$$2\left(2\frac{x}{u}dx-\frac{x^2}{u^2}du\right)+du+\left(-\frac{v^2}{u^2}du+2\frac{v}{u}dv\right)=0 $$
$$2\:d\left(\frac{x^2}{u}\right)+du+d\left(\frac{v^2}{u} \right)=0$$
The integration is possible because the coefficients of the differentials are constant.
$$2\frac{x^2}{u}+u+\frac{v^2}{u}=C$$